# Web Scraping WeatherUnderground

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I'm doing the project that reads the data every hour from WeatherUnderground and it saves the data into a txt file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime

def scrape_weather_data(url, time_selector, temperature_selector, 
humidity_selector, precip_selector, wind_speed_selector, 
pressure_selector, ammount_selector):
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  

driver.get(url)  # Enter The website

# Generate text file name based on day and hour
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
filename = f'dane_pogodowe_{current_time}.txt'

# Saving data into a .txt file
with open(filename, 'a') as file:
    time_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,time_selector)
    temperature_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,temperature_selector)
    humidity_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,humidity_selector)
    precip_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,precip_selector)
    wind_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, wind_speed_selector)
    pressure_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, pressure_selector)
    ammount_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ammount_selector)

    for i in range(len(time_elements)):
        time = time_elements[i].text.strip()
        temperature = temperature_elements[i].text.strip()
        humidity = humidity_elements[i].text.strip()
        precip = precip_elements[i].text.strip()
        wind = wind_elements[i].text.strip()
        pressure = pressure_elements[i].text.strip()
        ammount = ammount_elements[i].text.strip()

        file.write(f"Czas: {time}\n")
        file.write(f"Temperatura: {temperature}\n")
        file.write(f"Wilgotność: {humidity}\n")
        file.write(f"Szansa opadów: {precip}\n")
        file.write(f"Wiatr: {wind}\n")
        file.write(f"Ciśnienie: {pressure}\n")
        file.write(f"Ilość opadów: {ammount}\n")
        file.write("\n")
    file.write("------------------------------\n")

driver.quit()  # Close the Web browser

print("Dane pogodowe zostały zapisane.")

# URL
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/pl/kucoby'

# Selectors CSS
time_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) 
> td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-timeHour.mat-column- 
timeHour.ng-star-inserted > span'
temperature_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-temperature.mat- 
column-temperature.ng-star-inserted'
humidity_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-humidity.mat-column- 
humidity.ng-star-inserted'
precip_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-precipitation.mat- 
column-precipitation.ng-star-inserted'
wind_speed_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-wind.mat-column- 
wind.ng-star-inserted'
pressure_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-pressure.mat-column- 
pressure.ng-star-inserted'
ammount_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column- 
liquidPrecipitation.mat-column-liquidPrecipitation.ng-star- 
inserted'


# Calling a function and saving the Data
scrape_weather_data(url, time_selector, temperature_selector, 
humidity_selector, precip_selector, wind_speed_selector, 
pressure_selector, ammount_selector)
`
```

And the data reading is based on CSS_Selectors as you can tell, but the problem is that when it enters the website, the default setting is that it opens in the imperial system, not the metrical that i use. And i can't really convert it mathematically into metric system, due to the fact that the variables are saved as strings. There is a option on this website to convert data from imperial into metrical system, but to be fair i have no idea, how to implement it.

EDIT
[I found out the key that is responsible for setting the metric system:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqa3s.png)

Comment: you can convert a string to an int or float with `int()` or `float()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert (*typecast*) strings to `int` or `float` with the `int()` and `float()` methods like this:

```py
# convert a string to an integer
string = "123"
int_value = int(string)
print(int_value)


# convert a string to a float
string = "123.123"
float_value = float(string)
print(float_value)
```

You can then do whatever conversions you like...

this way, you would not need to modify the selenium part of the code (given that it is working).

Comment: Yes that was my first idea, the thing is that it wouldn't work with a wind column that is given as shown "4 mph E", I'd have to seperate it and i was wondering if i could work this out with selenium i tried driver.add_cookie({"name": "wu.Units", "value": "metric"}) but I didnt do much

Comment: why dont you just toggle to metric system from the UI?

Comment: @user22018490,  you can use the `split()` method to separate strings into numbers and units. `split(" ")`.

Comment: @MuratIshen because this project is supposed to be automatic - thats at least my proffesor says

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle to metric system from the UI directly in the website top-right corner. hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've added that in the Edit i posted. But how do i to that in code without interacting with UI? Using sellenium only?

Comment: yes you can toggle it to automatically by selenium.

Comment: how is that??? @Murat Ishen

Comment: can you provide the code where you try change to metric system?

Comment: i mean i tried to do that with selenium, i sent a new question 5 minutes ago, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409811/weatherunderground-web-scraping-choosing-different-measurements-systems