# WeatherUnderground Web Scraping - choosing different measurements systems

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

So I've been trying to change measurements systems. Default measurement system on the WeatherUnderground is set on imperial system.
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime

```
def scrape_weather_data(url, time_selector, temperature_selector, 
humidity_selector, precip_selector, wind_speed_selector, 
pressure_selector, ammount_selector):
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  

driver.get(url)  # Enter The website

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#wuSettings > i').click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#wuSettings-quick > div > 
a:nth-child(2)').click()

# Generate text file name based on day and hour
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
filename = f'dane_pogodowe_{current_time}.txt'

# Saving data into a .txt file
with open(filename, 'a') as file:
time_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,time_selector)
temperature_elements = 
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,temperature_selector)
humidity_elements = 
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,humidity_selector)
precip_elements = 
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,precip_selector)
wind_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
wind_speed_selector)
pressure_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
pressure_selector)
ammount_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
ammount_selector)

for i in range(len(time_elements)):
    time = time_elements[i].text.strip()
    temperature = temperature_elements[i].text.strip()
    humidity = humidity_elements[i].text.strip()
    precip = precip_elements[i].text.strip()
    wind = wind_elements[i].text.strip()
    pressure = pressure_elements[i].text.strip()
    ammount = ammount_elements[i].text.strip()

    file.write(f"Czas: {time}\n")
    file.write(f"Temperatura: {temperature}\n")
    file.write(f"Wilgotność: {humidity}\n")
    file.write(f"Szansa opadów: {precip}\n")
    file.write(f"Wiatr: {wind}\n")
    file.write(f"Ciśnienie: {pressure}\n")
    file.write(f"Ilość opadów: {ammount}\n")
    file.write("\n")
file.write("------------------------------\n")

driver.quit()  # Close the Web browser

 print("Dane pogodowe zostały zapisane.")

# URL
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/pl/kucoby'

# Selectors CSS
time_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) 
> td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-timeHour.mat-column- 
timeHour.ng-star-inserted > span'
temperature_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-temperature.mat- 
column-temperature.ng-star-inserted'
humidity_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-humidity.mat-column- 
humidity.ng-star-inserted'
precip_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-precipitation.mat- 
column-precipitation.ng-star-inserted'
wind_speed_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-wind.mat-column- 
wind.ng-star-inserted'
pressure_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-pressure.mat-column- 
pressure.ng-star-inserted'
ammount_selector = '#hourly-forecast-table > tbody > tr:nth- 
child(1) > td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column- 
liquidPrecipitation.mat-column-liquidPrecipitation.ng-star- 
inserted'


# Calling a function and saving the Data
scrape_weather_data(url, time_selector, temperature_selector, 
humidity_selector, precip_selector, wind_speed_selector, 
pressure_selector, ammount_selector)
```

`

So basically the most important 2 lines are :

```
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#wuSettings > i').click()

 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#wuSettings-quick > div > 
 a:nth-child(2)').click()
```

The first one is responsible to enter the settings[the gear icon] (which from where we can change the measurements systems), and the other one is responsible to click the 2nd option which is the metric system.

The problem is that when i try do that the output in my textfile is "------------------------------". I don't know why. It seems that is only working with selectors, that dont have such a path "a:nth-child". Because when i change that to celcius, then the imperial system becomes the selector that is"#wuSettings-quick > div > a:nth-child(1)". And the chosen selector is "#wuSettings-quick > div > a.button.selected" which works perfectly fine. How do i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Observe the `<div class="button-group">` element

[image: FC]

There are descendent [**pseudo**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) elements [**::before**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59706267/7429447) and [**::after**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70144313/7429447)

---

### Solution

To click on <kbd>°C</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) of the `<table>` element first and then inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159359/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/pl/kucoby")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#hourly-forecast-table")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#wuSettings > i"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#wuSettings-quick div a:nth-child(2)"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I've implemented those lines and it didnt work. It seems like page refreshes itself everytime it is choosing different measurement system

Comment: @user22018490 Nopes, it shouldn't. `#wuSettings-quick div a:nth-child(2)` always uniquely identifies **°C** provided you wait for the `<table>` to render after the initial pageload.

Comment: So how do I implement it so it would eventually work?

Comment: @user22018490 I'm still not sure where you are stuck. Can you just copy/paste and execute the code from the answer and let me know the status please?

Comment: I have copied and pasted and the result are exact the same, the output in textfile is "------------------------------"

Comment: @user22018490 Please revisit your question, your main issue was _It seems that is only working with selectors, that dont have such a path "a:nth-child". Because when i change that to celcius, then the imperial system becomes the selector that is"#wuSettings-quick > div > a:nth-child(1)". And the chosen selector is "#wuSettings-quick > div > a.button.selected" which works perfectly fine. How do i solve that?_. This answer addresses to issue to click on **°C** properly. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes and the sentence before that one was "The problem is that when i try to do that the output in my textfile is "------------------------------". I don't know why." Just because it has clicked the °C doesn't indicate that the problem has been solved